# Programmatically signed PDF document does not get the green checkmark after being signed using Acrobat Reader

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I have written an application to sign PDF documents and now I am able to sign any non-signed PDF document, and Adobe Reader shows the green checkmark. Moreover I can sign a file with multiple signatures and the results are ok.

But if I try to sign the document using Adobe Reader, when I sign it again, the result is that any signature prior to the last one does not get the green checkmark because Acrobat thinks that the document has changed. Then, if I sign the document again using Adobe Reader and my application, the next signatures get the green marks again. The problem appears with **the first adobe signature**, but I cannot get the reason.

Workflow:

1. Signature 1 with Acrobat => ok
2. Signature 2 with my app => the previous signatures are invalid, but this is ok
3. Signature 3 with Acrobat => signature 1 is invalid, but 2 and 3 are ok
4. Signature 4 with my app => signature 1 is invalid, but 2, 3 and 4 are ok

Could you please help me to identify and correct the problem?

Thank you in advance.

*The files:*

- [the original file](https://github.com/dealfonso/homework/blob/master/pdfproblem/A.pdf)
- [the file signed by me](https://github.com/dealfonso/homework/blob/master/pdfproblem/A.me.pdf) (it gets the green checkmark)
- [the file signed by acrobat](https://github.com/dealfonso/homework/blob/master/pdfproblem/A.acrobat.pdf) (it is correct).
- [the file signed by acrobat again](https://github.com/dealfonso/homework/blob/master/pdfproblem/A.acrobat.acrobat.pdf) (it is correct)
- [the file signed by acrobat an me](https://github.com/dealfonso/homework/blob/master/pdfproblem/A.acrobat.me.pdf) (fails to get the green check mark for the adobe's signed part)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change the **AcroForm** dictionary **DA** default appearance entry.

In the document signed by Adobe the **AcroForm** dictionary looks like this:

```
<</DA(/Helv 0 Tf 0 g )/DR<</Encoding<</PDFDocEncoding 8 0 R>>/Font<</Helv 6 0 R/MyriadPro-Regular 27 0 R/ZaDb 7 0 R>>>>/Fields[26 0 R]/SigFlags 3>>
```

After you signed that document it becomes this:

```
<</DA(/Helv 0 Tf 0 g)/DR<</Encoding<</PDFDocEncoding 8 0 R>>/Font<</Helv 6 0 R/MyriadPro-Regular 27 0 R/ZaDb 7 0 R>>>>/Fields[26 0 R 35 0 R]/SigFlags 3>>
```

I.e. you removed the trailing space character in the **DA** entry.